# Is this a stable implementation of mergesort

Tags: java, mergesort

I'm wondering is this implementation of MergeSort stable? More specifically if there are two elements with `compareTo` value of 0 then they will stay in the same order as the original array.

Thanks in advance.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class MergeSort {

    public static <E extends Comparable<E>> E[] sort(E[] original) {
        if (original.length < 2)
            return original;

        E[] left = (E[]) Array.newInstance(original.getClass().getComponentType(), original.length / 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < left.length; i++)
            left[i] = original[i];

        E[] right = (E[]) Array.newInstance(original.getClass().getComponentType(), original.length - left.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < right.length; i++)
            right[i] = original[left.length + i];

        left = sort(left);
        right = sort(right);

        return merge(left, right);
    }

    static <E extends Comparable<E>> E[] merge(E[] left, E[] right) {
        E[] out = (E[]) Array.newInstance(left.getClass().getComponentType(), left.length + right.length);

        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

        // Traverse both array
        while (i < left.length && j < right.length) {
            if (left[i].compareTo(right[j]) <= 0)
                out[k++] = left[i++];
            else
                out[k++] = right[j++];
        }

        // Store remaining elements of first array
        while (i < left.length)
            out[k++] = left[i++];

        // Store remaining elements of second array
        while (j < right.length)
            out[k++] = right[j++];
        //#)

        return out;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes，it is stable sort. Because this implementation pick element from left subset when `compareTo` return 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it says in the code:

```
    // Traverse both array
    while (i < left.length && j < right.length) {
        if (left[i].compareTo(right[j]) <= 0)
            out[k++] = left[i++];
        else
            out[k++] = right[j++];
    }
```

Here the important part is `<= 0`.
If two values are equal compareTo returns `0`. Therefore if the compared values are equal the one from the left array is taken, which means the **equal values will stay in the same order**.